# Converting decimal degrees to NMEA 0183 in python

Tags: python, gps, nmea

I am trying to convert GPS coordinates to NMEA sentences for the purpose of simulating GPS data. The goal is to feed this data into marine navigation software. However, the data I have generated seems to be incorrect. I am using this following function in python to convert GPS degrees in decimal format to NMEA 0183 format:

```
import math

def decdeg2nmea(dd):
    num = abs(dd)
    d = float(math.floor(num))
    m = num - d
    return '%i%f' % (int(degree), minutes * 60.00)
```

Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

The numbers need to be zero padded. The degrees should be represented by three characters for longitudes, i.e. 4 degrees east would be 004, and latitudes should be represented by two characters. Minutes should be represented by two characters plus the decimals. I.e. 4.5 degrees E would be 00430.0

Since you are using `abs` you are also losing the sign, so you need to reinsert that too. I think something like this should work for longitudes:

```
import math

def decdeg2nmea(dd):
    num = abs(dd)
    d = float(math.floor(num))
    m = num - d
    sign = '-' if dd < 0 else ''
    return sign+'%03i%02.5f' % (int(d), m * 60.00)
```